# Image Viewer - looking for feedback on my solution

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Hello**

i got my self more into javascript - without reading books and trying to learn by trial and error.

I have built a working **Image Viewer** tho i wanted to ask for **feedback** how i can solve this maybe more elegantly than my solution.

specially the `prev` and `next` button functions are a bit long and i also wanted to disable or not show the prev/next button when there is no image.

my solution would be to check if `the next().next().children().attr("src") of .img-selected` has a value and then disable/hide the button but i'm not sure if this is a good way to do it.

here is the codepen: http://codepen.io/mhn23/pen/MebWMe

Any feedback is greatly appreciated

Comment: everythings sems working fine to me, what is the problem ?

Comment: Hey John, it is working fine, but i thought there is maybe a better way to move the selected class instead of adding a temp id or general feedback!

Comment: Yes thats fine you can hide N/P buttons upon Last/First image respectively. Also you can do that by checking length of images data and based upon current image index you can hide N/P buttons.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/